# MongoDB C# Nullable Datetime Query

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to query a over mongoDB and I get the following error:

> Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression:
>   c.IndexMetadata.Indexed.**HasValue**.

where **Indexed** is a nullable datetime

my query is the following:

```
Collection.AsQueryable<Candidate>(c => !c.IndexMetadata.Indexed.HasValue || c.IndexMetadata.Updated.Value > c.IndexMetadata.Indexed.Value).ToList();
```

both **indexed** and **updated** are type of nullable datetime

I guess that's because there's no direct translation from HasValue into a mongo Query, any workaround?

Comment: You can't compare two fields with each other. You must compare them with constants unfortunately. A good way to figure out how to write a query is to write it in the shell first and make sure it works as you expect.

Comment: @CraigWilson I can refactor to avoid two columns comparison, but I still need to solve the hasValue error, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Perhaps you can use != null instead for now. File a jira issue at jira.mongodb.com in the C# project.

Comment: @CraigWilson the null comparison did the trick thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can compare the `DateTime?` to null instead of using `HasValue`:

```
Collection.AsQueryable<Candidate>(
    c => 
        c.IndexMetadata.Indexed == null || 
        c.IndexMetadata.Updated.Value > c.IndexMetadata.Indexed.Value).
    ToList();
```